# Moving a DOM Element in jQuery (Layer Slider)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, dom

jQuery noob here. Sorry if the question is really simple, I haven't been exposed to much jquery, though I am trying to learn.

I am attempting to move a DOM Element from one place to another, but I seem to be running into some errors.

When I attempt to test to see if the DOM exists I get indications that the element is not in the DOM:

```
if (jQuery('.ls-yourlogo').length) {
    alert('Found!');
} else {
    alert('NOT FOUND!');
}
```

I am trying to move **.ls-yourlogo** into **.ls-inner**.

I have tried several different things including:

```
jQuery('#layerslider_1').children('img').appendTo('#layerslider_1').children('.ls-inner');
```

also

```
    jQuery('.ls-yourlogo').appendTo('.ls-inner');
```

I do know that the **.ls-yourlogo** and the **.ls-inner** DOM elements are both created with jQuery. I'm not sure if that is what is causing the problem.

I am currently working with the Layer slider plugin for WordPress: http://codecanyon.net/item/layerslider-responsive-wordpress-slider-plugin-/1362246

```
  <div id="slider">
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"></script>
    <div class="ls-wp-fullwidth-container" style="height: 317px;">
        <div class="ls-wp-fullwidth-helper" style="height: 317px; width: 1349px; left: 0px;">
            <div id="layerslider_1" class="ls-wp-container ls-container ls-noskin" style="width: 1050px; height: 317px; margin: 0px auto; visibility: visible;">
            <div class="ls-webkit-hack"></div>
            <div class="ls-inner">
                <div class="ls-layer ls-active">
                    <img class="ls-s-1">
                    <p ></p>
                    <p ></p>
                </div>
                <div class="ls-layer" >
                    <img class="ls-s-1">
                </div>
            <div class="ls-circle-timer"></div>
            <div class="ls-loading-container"></div>
            <div class="ls-thumbnail-wrapper"></div>
            <div class="ls-shadow"></div>
            <img class="ls-yourlogo">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: if both those elements are created by script then your code to move them has to be executed after those elements are created... `jQuery('.ls-yourlogo').appendTo('.ls-inner');` looks good

Comment: Can you please provide a fiddle with proper indentation? I noticed a few tags that were not closed off.

Comment: @Arun P Johny 
<br>
How would I be able to wait for elements to be created then check for them? In the if statement above .ls-yourlogo is never found. 

C.S I believe someone already provided a jsfiddle. The not closed off DOM elements is because I had to copy and paste from the browser. 
100% of this part of the DOM is created by the plugin I referenced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found a solution for moving an element the Layer Slider DOM.

```
        jQuery('#layerslider_1').layerSlider({
        hoverPrevNext : false,
        cbInit              : function(element){
                                jQuery('.ls-yourlogo').appendTo('.ls-inner');
                                jQuery('.ls-thumbnail-slide > a').addClass('ls-thumbnail-style');

                              }
    });
```

The ID is of your layer slider that exists on the page. Mine happened to be 1 so its #layerslider_1. The next important part is the callback cbInit, inside this function you can make your appends and what ever other markup changes you want to make to the DOM. 
Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Dude you are a wizard! i spent all day trying to get an overlay to work and this was money!

Comment: I'm glad this could help someone, it took me a bit of research into layerslider to find it.

Answer (score 0):

[see this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fZ6dE/)The `</div>` tags in your html are not properly closed off, that might be contributing to part of your problem.  If I close a few off and run my code, it removes the element with the `class='ls-your-logo'` and appends it to the `<div class='ls-inner'>` which ends up being the same place as it was before.  Perhaps if you look at my fiddle, you can better close the div tags to how you want it to properly look

Comment: Different tags not being closed off is just me being bad at copy and paste. This part of the DOM is generated by a plugin for WordPress. 
I know the elements I am trying to manipulate are created dynamically. I do not know when they are created therefor can not access them.

Comment: I tested your fiddle. And the reason yours works is because you have manually created the DOM. This DOM is created by the plugin I referenced, the elements I am trying to manipulate are created (possibly by jQuery) dynamically. 

Even the test for .ls-yourlogo that works in your fiddle, only returns "NOT FOUND" in my code. How can I check for the creation of a DOM that is created dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

suggestion instead of you typing jQuery everytime use $ instead it makes it easier for you.

```
if ($('.ls-yourlogo')) {
    alert('Found!');
} else {
    alert('NOT FOUND!');
}
```

Also i would suggestion using #ids than classes because ids are lot faster to get in Jquery than classes. And Make sure you call your the script that makes  .is-yourlogo class first before checking if it exits.

Comment: You should look for $('.ls-yourlogo')).length

Comment: $('.ls-yourlogo').length never hits for me. When throwing it into an IF, I always get the else.

Comment: Why does it never find .ls-yourlogo?

Comment: The reason it may not find $('Is-yourLogo') because it it doesn't exist in your dom when you call this statement.